# Does material nested tree support siblings?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented material tree using the following code,I tried searching the stackoverflow for any implementation of siblings in mat-tree and I could not find.Does angular material support support siblings in nested tree? If so how can this be achieved using the below html code.

```
 <mat-tree  [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;" matTreeNodeToggle (click)="selectednode = node"
      (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)" [ngClass]="{ 'background-highlight':selectednode === node  }">
      <div style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed" [style.left]="contextMenuPosition.x"
        [style.top]="contextMenuPosition.y" [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu">
      </div>
      <mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="add(node)">Add</button>
        <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="selectednode && selectednode.id ===0 ? false: true"
          (click)="remove(node)">Remove</button>
      </mat-menu>
      <mat-icon class="folder-icon-spacing" fontSet="far" [fontIcon]="'fa-folder'">
      </mat-icon>
      <div class="node-format item-font">
        {{node.name}} </div>
      <div class="align-setproperties item-font" (click)="showProperties(node)">Set Properties</div>
    </mat-tree-node>
    <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
      <div class="mat-tree-node" (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)" (click)="selectednode = node"
        [ngClass]="{ 'background-highlight':selectednode === node  }">
        <!-- <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.name"> -->
        <mat-icon class="folder-icon-spacing" fontSet="far"
          [fontIcon]="treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'fa-folder-open' : 'fa-folder'">
        </mat-icon>
        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror chevron-color">
          {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
        </mat-icon>
        <!-- </button> -->
        <div class="node-format item-font">
          {{node.name}} </div>
        <div class="align-setproperties item-font" (click)="showProperties(node)">Set Properties</div>
      </div>
      <div [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)" role="group">
        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
      <div style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed" [style.left]="contextMenuPosition.x"
        [style.top]="contextMenuPosition.y" [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu">
      </div>
      <mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="add(node)">Add</button>
        <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="selectednode && selectednode.id ===0 ? false: true"
          (click)="remove(node)">Remove</button>
      </mat-menu>
    </mat-nested-tree-node>
  </mat-tree>
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this using the *ngFor loop inside parent and child like this where node.items contains a array of siblings.

```
  <div  *ngFor="let sibling of node.items" >
          {{sibling}}
  </div>
```

Short snippet of the code

```
 <mat-tree  [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;" matTreeNodeToggle (click)="selectednode = node"
        [ngClass]="{ 'background-highlight':selectednode === node  }">
          <div style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed" [style.left]="contextMenuPosition.x"
            [style.top]="contextMenuPosition.y" [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu">
          </div>
          <mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="add(node)">Add</button>
            <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="selectednode && selectednode.id ===0 ? false: true"
              (click)="remove(node)">Remove</button>
          </mat-menu>
          <mat-icon class="folder-icon-spacing" fontSet="far" [fontIcon]="'fa-folder'">
          </mat-icon>
          <div class="node-format item-font">
            {{node.name}} </div>
          
          <div class="align-setproperties item-font" (click)="showProperties(node)">Set Properties</div>
         
           
          <div style="display:block" *ngFor="let sibling of node.items" matTreeNodeOutlet  >
              {{sibling}}
          </div>
         
          
        </mat-tree-node>
        <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
          <div class="mat-tree-node"  (click)="selectednode = node" 
            [ngClass]="{ 'background-highlight':selectednode === node  }">
            <!-- <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.name"> -->
            <mat-icon class="folder-icon-spacing" fontSet="far"
              [fontIcon]="treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'fa-folder-open' : 'fa-folder'">
            </mat-icon>
            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror chevron-color">
              {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
            </mat-icon>
            <!-- </button> -->
            <div class="node-format item-font">
              {{node.name}} </div>
            <div class="align-setproperties item-font" (click)="showProperties(node)">Set Properties</div>
          </div>
          <div [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)" role="group">
            <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
          <div style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed" [style.left]="contextMenuPosition.x"
            [style.top]="contextMenuPosition.y" [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu">
          </div>
          <mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="add(node)">Add</button>
            <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="selectednode && selectednode.id ===0 ? false: true"
              (click)="remove(node)">Remove</button>
          </mat-menu>
          <div  *ngFor="let sibling of node.items" >
              {{sibling}}
          </div>
        </mat-nested-tree-node>
      </mat-tree>
```